# Visual Studio 2019 - How can I keep build Output and Error List when reloading a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

A common use case is CMake regenerate being triggered by ZERO_CHECK when building and then encountering a compiler error.

Regenerating CMake (likely due to CMake changes like from changing commits or just a minor adjustment) is correctly processed before MSBuild content so the build itself is "current" but It can trigger Visual Studio to ask the user if they want to reload the solution after the build completes.  It must always be answered with Reload Solution or your solution explorer is FUBAR.

Unfortunately, reloading the solution erases all content in the error list and the output window.  This means the build must be run a second time if there was a problem which can be time consuming on larger projects.

Years ago, I figured out what setting controlled this behavior and disabled it which worked splendidly on my old machine.

Now on a new machine I can no longer recall what that setting is or find it in the Visual Studio settings.   I get a lot of false positives about unrelated output window or error list problems when I tried searching for this feature.